# Sumar valores en listas

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

1
Necesito sumar valores en una lista de python, donde la suma de estos valores no se excedan de un limite propuesto y que la suma sea asignado a otra lista. Por ejemplo: Tengo un límite se suma `lim=9` y una lista `lista=[3,3,3,3,3,3,3]`, necesito que me devuelva `lista2=[9,9,3]`. El código siguiente no me devuelve lo esperado.

```
l = 1.5 
cant = 10         #longitud de la lista
lb = 9            #limite
m = 0
lista = []
lista2 = []
for i in range(cant): #crea lista
    lista.append(l)
print(lista)

for j in lista:
    m += j

    for p in lista:
        if l<m<=lb:
            lista2.append(m)
            lista.remove(p)

print(j)
print(lista2)
```

Comment: Esta pregunta ya había sido hecha (y borrada). Repito aqui lo que dije entonces. 
No veo la necesidad de dos bucles anidados (ni de quitar elementos de la lista original, que supongo que no debería tocarrse). Basta inicializar `m` con cero, y para cada elemento de la lista verificar si `m+j` excede `lb`. En ese caso, metes `m` en la lista del resultado y pones `m` a cero. Finalmente, antes de pasar a otra iteración del bucle, sumas `j` a `m`.

Comment: ya fue respondida, amigo @abulafia. Mira la respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que el acumulador `m` no lo reinicias cuando se pasa del límite, además de que debes añadirlo justo antes de que se pase, no en cada iteración del bucle. Así mismo, suele ser peligroso modificar la lista mientras la estás recorriendo.

Te propongo la siguiente solución:

```
m = 0
for j in lista:
    if l < m+j <= lb:
        m += j
    else:
        lista2.append(m)
        m = j
```

Podemos adaptar este código para que sea algo más *pythónico* con *iterables*:

```
def reduce_suma(iterable, l, lb):
    m = 0
    for j in iterable:
        if l < m+j <= lb:
            m += j
        else:
            yield m
            m = j

lista2 = list(reduce_suma(lista, l, lb))
```

---

**Edición**: eliminado límite inferior y añadido último sumando.

```py
for j in lista:
    if m+j <= lb:
        m += j
    else:
        lista2.append(m)
        m = j
else:
    lista2.append(m)
```

Comment: ChemaCortes hay un problema en el código. me está devolviendo en el primer valor de la lista [0]

Comment: @AlbertoTorrealba En tu código hay un límite inferior que he respetado y que ya incumple el primer elemento de la lista. Si lo quitas, entonces no sale ese 0. También falta de añadir el último sumando. Ya cambio el código.

Comment: perfecto @ChemaCortes, ya coloqué como aceptada tu respuesta

Comment: he encontrado algo curioso. si en las variables uso l = 0.4, cant = 15 y lb = 6, el resultado esperado debería ser [6], pero me devuelve [5.60000000000005, 0.4]

Comment: Es un problema conocido de la representación del números en coma flotante (["Why are floating-point calculations so inaccurate?"](https://docs.python.org/3.7/faq/design.html?highlight=decimal#why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate)). El 0.4 se almacena como '0.40000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625', por lo que si lo sumas 15 sale un resultado mayor de 6 (concretamente '6.000000000000000333066907388'). En el [tutorial de python](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) tienes información sobre cómo evitar estos problemas.

Comment: nuevamente muchas gracias! @ChemaCortes